# 83.5x83.5@2x app icon is required for iPad apps targeting iOS 9.0 and later

Tags: xcode, image

Just saw this warning after upgrading to Xcode 7.2. Why is this warning appearing all of a sudden with 7.2/9.2? I'm guessing this is for iPad Pro support? Does this just mean 167x167 since it's at 2x ?

[image: Xcode warning]

EDIT: I do see that (now in Xcode 7.2) there is a space for this (iPad Pro) icon in the asset catalog under General/App Icons and Launch Images

[image: App icon placeholder]

EDIT: Is it possible to turn off this warning? e.g. if there is no intention to target iPad Pro?

Comment: Notice the "pt", that is points, not pixels. Can't wait to see 83.3333333... pt for 3x. Or perhaps Jony is off his meds.

Comment: After adding the new image to the image set the error message is still showing. It goes away when you build or run.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is for the iPad Pro. The image should be 167x167 pixels. This will display on both the 9.7" and 12.9" iPad Pro at 264 pixels per inch.

Comment: OK thanks, but I'm not clear what you mean by 72 PPI as well.

Comment: Reason I ask is that the iPad Pro will display images at 264 ppi

Comment: The file name is important?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa No, the initial file name is not important. It will change the name during installation